# Solve for the third dihedral angle in an intersection of three planes

Tags: trigonometry

Three planes *A*, *B* and *C* intersect at point P.  The dihedral angle between *A* and *B* is $\theta$ and the dihedral angle between *B* and *C* is $\psi$.

1. Solve for the dihedral angle between by *A* and *C*.
2. Planes *A* and *B* intersect plane *C* in two lines that form angle QPR.  That is, point Q lies in both *A* and *C*, and point R lies in both *B* and *C*. Solve for the angle of QPR in terms of $\theta$ and $\psi$.
3. Does this fall under trigonometry? If not, what?

Comment: You may want to tag this as differential geometry too.

Comment: No, differential geometry involves derivatives. This is pure vector geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: The third angle is not uniquely determined by $\theta$ and $\psi$. If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the unit normal vectors to the planes $A$, $B$ and $C$, then the problem is equivalent to determining $a \cdot c$ from $a \cdot b$ and $c \cdot b$, which cannot be done. (Think of $b$ being fixed; then giving values of $a \cdot b$ and $c \cdot b$ constrains $a$ and $c$ to lie on certain cones around $b$, but the positions of $a$ and $c$ on these cones are arbitrary.)